# Selenium Test case stop by getting error on after method

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-extent-report

I have a project where I use Testng and use extend report for reporting.I have 64 total test case but when 24 number test case, when running my after method, shows error and stop the execution.Can we continue execution?

> is there Any suggestion how can I over come from stop execution

Here is my after method class

```
    @AfterMethod
public void setTestResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException {

    String screenShot = CaptureScreenShot.captureScreen(wd, CaptureScreenShot.generateFileName(result));

    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        test.log(Status.FAIL, result.getName());
        test.log(Status.FAIL,result.getThrowable());
        test.fail("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        test.log(Status.PASS, result.getName());
        test.pass("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        test.skip("Test Case : " + result.getName() + " has been skipped");
    }

    extent.flush();
    wd.quit();
}
```

Here Is my CaptureScreenShot Class

```
public class CaptureScreenShot {
private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd SSS");

public static String captureScreen(WebDriver driver, String screenName) throws IOException{

    TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File src = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    String dest ="C:/xampp//htdocs/Automation_report/Test-ScreenShots"+screenName+".png";

    File target = new File(dest);
    FileUtils.copyFile(src, target);

    return dest;
}

public static String generateFileName(ITestResult result){
    Date date = new Date();
    String fileName = result.getName()+ "_" + dateFormat.format(date);
    return fileName;

}
}
```

I am writing test case This way

```
@test
public void DetailsPageRedirectToPartnerSite_VRBO() throws InterruptedException {
    test = extent.createTest("Details PageRedirecToPartner Site");

}
```

> I am getting following error

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.size(FileChannelImpl.java:315)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1145)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1088)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1040)
at vrs.CaptureScreenShot.captureScreen(CaptureScreenShot.java:25)
at vrs.BedroomvillasProduction.setTestResult(BedroomvillasProduction.java:2320)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:786)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `test.fail("Screen Shot : " + test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));` should be responsible. what is `test` here?

Comment: using this I am taking a screenshot and attached my report

Comment: Agreed, but share its implementation as well in the question  and where is `test` declared?

Comment: I added screenshot class and my test case format...Please let me know what else information you need

Comment: Just check when any of your test case fails and the flow reaches the `captureScreenshot` method, does it throw any exception? If yes, please share the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: @zsbappa - What do you mean by _shows error and stop the execution_? `@AfterMethod` does not abort test execution. So I would request you to please add a bit more clarity to your question. Irrespective of what sort of exceptions are raised by `@AfterMethod` the maximum that can happen is the method gets aborted but execution would continue. To the best of my knowledge ExtentReports does not resort to invoking `System.exit()` anywhere as well.

Comment: I added the error which shows and stop executions

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't look to be complete, Yet a simple search of `java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException` shall let you know whats making the program to exit and stop the execution.

Comment: yes, I search but not get any perfect solution....